# return the closest value to value being searched

Tags: sql, pdw-file-browser

`enter code here`I need to pair vehicles by type and then secondly by fuel consumption. the fuel consumptions may not match and in that event the closest is chosen. the same vehicle cannot be used to pair more than once. example of the type of data i'm talking about is below

```
create table #table1
(
vehicleid varchar(2),
typed varchar(5),
fuelconsumption int
)


create table #table2
(
vehicleid varchar(2),
typed varchar(5),
fuelconsumption int
)


INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES('x1','car',5);
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES('x2','car',4);
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES('x3','car',8);

INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b1','car',7);
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b2','car',8);
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b3','car',9);
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b4','car',10);
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b5','car',11);
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b6','truck',15);
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('b7','truck',4);
```

which will return output like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7r6S.png)

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer may be product specific.)

Comment: updated with code and sample result

Comment: I have tried using a while loop to cycle through the vehicles in table 1 at a time and returning the first match based a rank of fuel consumption. two problems: it choses the same vehicle twice and choses the highest/lowest fuel consumption always as I am not doing a comparison of whats closest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not be a full answer (still working out the details), if you start with this you will get a list of best matching vehicle IDs in ascending order:

```
    SELECT baseID = ibase.vehicleid,
           matchID = im.vehicleid,
           rowNum = ROW_NUMBER()
                    OVER (PARTITION BY ibase.vehicleid
                          ORDER BY ABS(ibase.fuelconsumption - im.fuelconsumption)) 
      FROM #table1 ibase
             INNER JOIN #table2 im ON ibase.typed = im.typed
```

From here you should be able to loop through picking up "first" instances of the "b" vehicles

Full answer (note: I loathe cursors, but this works):

```
DROP TABLE #results
CREATE TABLE #results ( vehicleid1 VARCHAR(2), vehicleid2 VARCHAR(2), diff INT, rownum INT )

INSERT INTO #results ( vehicleid1, vehicleid2, diff, rownum ) 
SELECT baseID = ibase.vehicleid,
       matchID = im.vehicleid,
       diff = ABS(ibase.fuelconsumption - im.fuelconsumption),
       rowNum = ROW_NUMBER()
                    OVER (
                        PARTITION BY ibase.vehicleid
                        ORDER BY ABS(ibase.fuelconsumption - im.fuelconsumption))
  FROM #table1 ibase
       INNER JOIN #table2 im ON ibase.typed = im.typed 

-- The cursor ensures we get the real best match so we do not accidentally
-- assign a best match which is a _better_ match for another vehicle
DECLARE CUR_ CURSOR FOR SELECT vehicleid1 FROM #results ORDER BY diff
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(2)

OPEN CUR_
FETCH CUR_ INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Remove all matches other than the BEST match
    DELETE r
      FROM #results r
     WHERE r.vehicleid1 = @id
       AND r.rownum <> (SELECT MIN(ir.rownum) FROM #results ir WHERE ir.vehicleid1 = @id)

    -- Remove all other matches which use the remaining matched vehicle 
    DELETE r
      FROM #results r
     WHERE r.vehicleid1 <> @id
       AND r.vehicleid2 = (SELECT ir.vehicleid2 FROM #results ir where ir.vehicleid1 = @id)

    FETCH CUR_ INTO @id
END
CLOSE CUR_
DEALLOCATE CUR_

SELECT * FROM #results
```

Non-cursor solution:

```
DROP TABLE #results
CREATE TABLE #results ( vehicleid1 VARCHAR(2), vehicleid2 VARCHAR(2), diff INT, rownum INT )

INSERT INTO #results ( vehicleid1, vehicleid2, diff, rownum ) 
SELECT baseID = ibase.vehicleid,
       matchID = im.vehicleid,
       diff = ABS(ibase.fuelconsumption - im.fuelconsumption),
       rowNum = ROW_NUMBER()
                    OVER (
                        PARTITION BY ibase.vehicleid
                        ORDER BY ABS(ibase.fuelconsumption - im.fuelconsumption))
  FROM #table1 ibase
       INNER JOIN #table2 im ON ibase.typed = im.typed 

DECLARE @id VARCHAR(2)
WHILE EXISTS( SELECT vehicleid1 FROM #results GROUP BY vehicleid1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 
           @id = r.vehicleid1
      FROM #results r
            INNER JOIN (SELECT i.vehicleid1 FROM #results i GROUP BY i.vehicleid1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) i
              ON r.vehicleid1 = i.vehicleid1
     ORDER BY r.diff

    -- Remove all matches other than the BEST match
    DELETE r
      FROM #results r
     WHERE r.vehicleid1 = @id
       AND r.rownum <> (SELECT MIN(ir.rownum) FROM #results ir WHERE ir.vehicleid1 = @id)

    -- Remove all other matches which use the remaining matched vehicle 
    DELETE r
      FROM #results r
     WHERE r.vehicleid1 <> @id
       AND r.vehicleid2 = (SELECT ir.vehicleid2 FROM #results ir where ir.vehicleid1 = @id)

END

SELECT * FROM #results
```

Comment: I see what you are doing but you still have the issue of picking the same vehicle in table 2 twice potentially as both x1 and x2 are closest to b1 and both rank this as number 1.

Comment: I am using pdw which doesn't support cursors. I think i'll have to use a while?

Comment: a lot of the things you are trying to do with this statement are not possible in pdw. eg. from clause not allowed in delete statement

Comment: I suggest you add sql-pdw or similar to the question's tags so that others with more domain-specific knowledge can help.

Comment: there is no such option. just pdw file browser

Comment: ok I have now reworked the last solution provided and it gives me the outcome i'd expect